# Java bit unsigned shifting (>>>) give strange result

Tags: java, byte-shifting

I have this code:

```
int i = 255;
byte b = (byte) i;
int c;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString( i));
System.out.println("b = " + b); // b = -1
c=b>>>1;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString( c));
System.out.println(c);
```

But I can't understand how it works. I think that unsigned shifting to `255(11111111)` should give me `127(0111111)` but it doesn't. Is my assumption wrong?

Comment: What is the maximum value a `byte` can take?

Comment: i know that in java we have signed byte with range -127 to 127, but in representative 255 in binary i have true 11111111

Comment: Bit shifts in Java operate on ints, not bytes.

Comment: sorry if cant find duplicate. oh... i must better learn english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shift operators including `>>>` operate on `int`s. The value of `b`, which is `-1` because `byte` is signed, is promoted to `int` before the shift. That is why you see the results that you see.

The reason why `255` is re-interpreted as `-1` is that 255 has all its eight bits set to one. When you assign that to a signed 8-bit type of `byte`, it is interpreted as `-1` following [*two's complement*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) rules.

Comment: but if i do System.out.println(b>>>1); i get that too. what i must do for shift byte?

Comment: That's right, because of Java's promotion rules `b>>>1` means `((int)b) >>> 1`. It's the promotion of `b` to `int` that adds all these ones - that's required to keep the value equal to the original `-1`.

Comment: This question is a duplicate. Please vote to close instead of answering.

Answer (score 1):

this is how you can get the expected result

```
c = (0xFF & b) >>> 1;
```

see dasblinkenlight's answer for details

Comment: This question is a duplicate. Please vote to close instead of answering.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this, and you will understand:**

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i)); // 11111111
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(b)); // 11111111111111111111111111111111
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(c)); // 1111111111111111111111111111111
```

Variable `int i` equals 255, so the first print makes sense.

Variable `byte b` equals -1, because you store 255 in a single byte.

- But when you call `Integer.toBinaryString(b)`, the compiler converts `b` from `byte` to `int`, and `(int)-1 == FFFFFFFFh == 11111111111111111111111111111111b`, hence the second print.

Variable `int c` equals `b>>>1`, so the third print makes sense.